# How to concurrency promise limit to specific number?

Tags: node.js

In my code, the executing promise is 1 by 1. its not concurrency concept. how to convert to concurrency with limit 8 promise. so its like a create a pool with limit 8 promise. then, push and read promise output realtime.

example.

if in 1 second it can done 2 promise job, then it will output 2 promise. and fill again the pool with 2 new promise job.

i dont want it wait 8 promise job done in sametime, and start to fill pool with 8 job again.

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
import { load } from 'cheerio';

(async () => {
    const response = await fetch('https://hentairead.com/page/1/');

    const $ = load(await response.text());

    const totalPage = $('span.pages')
                        .text()
                        .match(/\d{3,}/g)
                        .toString();

    for(let page = 1; page <= totalPage; page++)
    {
        const response = await fetch(`https://hentairead.com/page/${page}/`);

        const $ = load(await response.text());

        $('div.item-thumb.c-image-hover > a').each((index, item) => {
            console.log(item.attribs.title);
        });
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
import { load } from 'cheerio';
import {CPromise} from "c-promise2";

(async () => {
    const response = await fetch('https://hentairead.com/page/1/');

    const $ = load(await response.text());

    const totalPage = $('span.pages')
                        .text()
                        .match(/\d{3,}/g)
                        .toString();

    const fetchPage= async (page)=>{
        const response = await fetch(`https://hentairead.com/page/${page}/`);

        const $ = load(await response.text());

        $('div.item-thumb.c-image-hover > a').each((index, item) => {
            console.log(item.attribs.title);
        });
    }

    await CPromise.all(function*(){
       for(let page = 1; page <= totalPage; page++){
          yield fetchPage(page);
       }
    }, {concurrency: 8});
})();
```